# Asynctask not fetching data without strict mode in Android > 2.2

Tags: android

I am using async to fetch data. It's working fine in Android 2.2, but it doesn't show any result when running in Android 4.1.

If I use strict mode, it shows a result on 4.1, but strict mode doesn't work on Android 2.2.

Without strict mode, I am getting an `Error converting result` exception.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.assignment, container, false);

    getActivity().setTitle("Assignments");

    assignments = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    session = new SessionManagement(getActivity());
    // StrictMode.enableDefaults();

    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    username = user.get(SessionManagement.KEY_NAME);
    school = user.get(SessionManagement.KEY_SCHOOL);

    // getData();
    new dataget2().execute();

    return view;
}

private class dataget2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        getData(username, school);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(isr, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");

            }
            isr.close();

            result = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error coverting result " + e.toString());

        }
        try {
            // String s = "";
            // ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list =

            new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                // assign[i]=json.getString("ASSIGNMENT_TEXT");
                HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();

                temp.put("subject", "" + json.getString("SUBJECT") + "");
                temp.put("assign", "" + json.getString("ASSIGNMENT_TEXT")
                        + "");
                temp.put("date", "" + json.getString("Date") + "");
                list.add(temp);

                // listItems.add(""+json.getString("ASSIGNMENT_TEXT")+"");
            }
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), list,
                    R.layout.custom_row_view, new String[] { "subject",
                            "assign", "date" }, new int[] { R.id.text2,
                            R.id.text1, R.id.text3 }

            );

            assignments.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing data " + e.toString());

        }
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Please Wait..",
                true);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }

    void getData(String username, String school) {

        try {
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://npaneer.iguardianerp.co.in/assignment.php");

            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            // tv.setText("vhpppi");

            nameValuePairs
                    .add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username)); // $Edittext_value
                                                                        // =
                                                                        // $_POST['Edittext_value'];

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("schoolSelected",
                    school));
            // tv.setText("vhisjdskdj");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            isr = entity.getContent();

        } // try terminated

        catch (Exception e) {
            // dialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }

    } // void

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is a little messy i think. **onPostExecute** method is originally designed only for UI updates but you are performing there file processing - this is not good idea.

According to well designated application logic file processing, networking and other operations that generally takes some time should be executed in background thread(s).

So my opinion is to move whole logic for file processing and `JSON` generating into **doInBackground** method and then when data are ready only update Adapter.

**Note:** Please change name of *dataget2*  to *DataGetWorker* or something else. Try to follow some class naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `try`/`catch` block that reads from the result stream in `onPostExecute` into `getData`.

I think that although you obtain a reference to the stream in the background thread, you have not actually read from it yet.  You then pass the stream back to the UI thread, then read from it in `onPostExecute`, which performs a network operation.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code while executing your AsyncTask:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
  new dataget2().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
} else {
  new dataget2().execute();
}
```

> If your android:targetSdkVersion is set to 13 or higher, and you are
>   running on Android 4.x or higher, AsyncTask will use an Executor that
>   executes only one task at a time. Otherwise, you get the older
>   parallel execution behavior. It is possible that this behavior kicked
>   in on some patchlevel release of 3.2, but current indications are that
>   it did not.

[Read more.](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/04/20/asynctask-threading-regression-confirmed.html)